# Is this a consequence of the uncountability of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just a random curiosity I developed now:

Does the uncountability of a set mean that we can't find numbers $a$ and $b$ in $a<x<b$ being $a<b$ for which $x$ doesn't exist?

For example, in a countable set ($\mathbb{N}$ for example), there is $a=2$ and $b=3$, $x$ does not exist. But for $\mathbb{R}$, I guess it's impossible to find $a$'s and $b$'s for which $x$ wouldn't exist.

I just had the idea when I was looking at some properties of the reals in an analysis book, could it be a plausible definition for a uncontable set of numbers? Perhaps it's true and it may be obvious but in the near past I made some mistakes by presuming something as obvious - I'm afraid of assuming this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The set $A=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ is uncountable, and $1\in A$ and $2\in A$, but there is no $a\in A$ such that $1<a<2$. In the other direction, $\Bbb Q$ is countable, and whenever $p,q\in\Bbb Q$ with $p<q$, there is an $r\in\Bbb Q\cap(p,q)$.

Let $\langle X,\le\rangle$ be a linearly ordered set. $X$ is a *dense* linear order if it has the property that you’re interested in: for any $x,y\in X$ with $x<y$ there is a $z\in X\cap(x,y)$. $\Bbb Q$ is a countable dense linear order. (In fact, up to isomorphism it’s the only countable dense linear order without endpoints.) $\Bbb R$ is an uncountable dense linear order. The middle-thirds Cantor set $C$ is an uncountable linear order that is not dense: the endpoints of each removed interval are adjacent in $C$. And $\Bbb Z$ is a countable linear order that is very far from being dense.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Later in the book I discovered the concept of density, I got curious about two things :  **1**: Is there a way to measure density? From what I am thinking about, it seems only to be possible for countable sets; **2**: Are the functions with different densities in different intervals?

Comment: @Gustavo: (1) Not in any very useful way. You could look at the set $S$ of points of $X$ having an immediate successor in the order and compare $|S|$ with $|X|$, but that’s a fairly crude measure. (2) This kind of density applies only to sets in a linear order, not to functions. A subset of a linear order can certainly be dense in some intervals and not dense in others: consider the set $\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\cup(\Bbb Q\cap[1,2]$.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, Professor. I was reasoning the following statement: A function is a mapping $f:A \rightarrow B$, would it be possible to find a function in one variable that could have the set $B$ as with different densities in different intervals? I changed the argument: From function to set of a function, does it make any difference?

Comment: @Gustavo: *Different densities* doesn’t really make sense: a linear order either is a dense linear order or is not a dense linear order. But if that’s what you mean, then sure: take $f(x)=x$ if $x\le 0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\ge 0$, and $f$ takes the negative reals to a densely ordered set and the positive reals to a singleton, which is definitely not densely ordered.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @Gustavo: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Uncountability of a set isn't related to the notion of ordering of the elements in the set. Consider the complex numbers as an example. There is no ordering (which makes it an ordered field, at least) and still it is an uncountable set. So your question really assumes that there is an ordering within of a specific type. As such it is ill-framed.

Answer (score 3):

For any uncountable limit ordinal $\alpha$ and any $x\in\alpha$, we have $x+1\in\alpha$. But there is no $y$ such that $x<y<x+1$.